# Need help using <elf.h>

Tags: c, linux, elf

How do I wrap `Elf32_Ehdr` and `Elf64_Ehdr` so that on 64 bit architectures `Elf64_Ehdr` and `Elf32_Ehdr` on 32 bit ones?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <elf.h>
#if UINTPTR_MAX == 0xffffffff
#define Elf_Ehdr Elf32_Ehdr
#define Elf_Phdr Elf32_Phdr
#else
#define Elf_Ehdr Elf64_Ehdr
#define Elf_Phdr Elf64_Phdr
#endif
```

Comment: why is this wrong? `void*p;..initilize p omited ..p = (Elf32_Ehdr*)p;`,when I try to reference `p->e_ident`,got an warning: `warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer`. Why the cast doesn't work?

Comment: The statement `p = (Elf32_Ehdr*)p;` is completely a no-op. It converts the value of `p` to an expression of type `Elf32_Ehdr*`, then assigns the result back to `p` which implicitly converts back to type `void *`.

Comment: I did the cast in order to use the `void*` as `Elf32_Ehdr*`,that's wrong?

Comment: No, but `p` has type `void *` and that won't change. If you declare a new pointer `Elf32_Ehdr *p2` and assign the casted `p` to that, it will work.

Comment: Forget casting. Just assign the pointer and it will work. Casting almost always indicates that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @R.. ,this works at compile time,how to do it run time? Say if the ELF file(as input parameter) is 32 bit,use `Elf32_Ehdr`,otherwise use `Elf64_Ehdr`? How can I avoid write the similar code twice in this case? Is there such a trick?

Comment: @R.. You missed his point.  What if R__ wants to use the _same_ compilation to read both 32 and 64 bit elf files?  In Haskell you can do this with the `elf` package, which reads Elf32 and Elf64 into a common structure.  With pure C and `elf.h` I think you'd want to have a union of the Elf structures, a tag field, and set of helper functions to make this smooth.

Comment: @Thomas M. DuBuisson ,is that possible to put Elf32 and Elf64 into a common structure when their size of different?

Comment: @R__ Sure it is, the elf package that does exactly that is on [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/elf/0.26/doc/html/Data-Elf.html#t:Elf).  Two things of note: 1) The fields take on the larger size (so, 32 bit addresses from ELF32 are still stored as a 64 bit word) 2) This library can parse ELF headers, but not write them back out.

Comment: The other way to do it is including the same file twice, once with 32-bit defines and once with 64-bit defines, to generate two versions of the code, then calling the right one conditionally.